# Is it possible to create a numpy.memmap of array of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-memmap, memmap

I have a (4,) arrays that I want to save to the disk (The sizes I am working with can not fit into memory so I need to dynamically load what I need). However, I want to have that in a single `numpy.memmap`. Not sure if it is possible but any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I have this without `numpy.memmap`

```py
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [2,3,4,5]
arr3 = [3,4,5,6]
arr4 = [4,5,6,7]
data = []
data.extend([arr1])
data.extend([arr2])
data.extend([arr3])
data.extend([arr4])
print(data)
```

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

I want to be able to do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.memmap('./file1', np.dtype('O'), mode='w+', shape=(4,))
arr1[:] = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = np.memmap('./file2', np.dtype('O'), mode='w+', shape=(4,))
arr2[:] = [2,3,4,5]
arr3 = np.memmap('./file3', np.dtype('O'), mode='w+', shape=(4,))
arr3[:] = [3,4,5,6]
arr4 = np.memmap('./file4', np.dtype('O'), mode='w+', shape=(4,))
arr4[:] = [4,5,6,7]
data = []
data.extend([arr1])
data.extend([arr2])
data.extend([arr3])
data.extend([arr4])
print (data)
```

> `[memmap([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object), memmap([2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=object), memmap([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=object), memmap([4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)]`

This requires me to create different files per array and I really want to have a single `memmap` that would handle the entire mini-arrays of 4. Can someone provide a way to do this using `memmaps`?

The ability to extend i.e. `data.extend()` is important as I don't know how many mini-arrays I have.

Comment: Careful when creating `O` dtype `memmap`.  This just saves pointers to objects to the file, not the actual objects.  Those objects still exist only in your current memory.  I can read your `arr1` in another session only if the values are integers less than 256.  Anything else gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't think you can practically piece together memory mapped chunks from different files into a consecutive range of memory. The underlying `mmap()` API allows hinting own addresses, but it would be a pain to piece together multiple files in a reliable and robust way. Also, the granularity would be the architecture's page size. You cannot piece together any arbitrary size, only multiples of a page size, typically n * 4096 bytes.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the tip. I actually have very large numbers. I have it as np.ndarray right now but I want to convert it to memmap somehow. Probably using np.dtype('O') is wrong. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @blubberdiblub, thanks for this insight, the mini-arrays don't need to be implemented as memmap. I am more looking for loading these mini-arrays dynamically so I don't have to load the entire list of arrays into memory as I can't (even with 64GB RAM memory)
So I need a single `memmap` that have these mini-arrays somehow.

Comment: @Kour I'm not aware of a numpy array type that acts as a kind of proxy to some piecewise loading/caching mechanism (which doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exists). Maybe there's some way to solve the problem on the OS level? Maybe you can actually concatenate the array into a big file and afterwards (if necessary) split them again? Or maybe let device mapper do it for you, if you're on a linux system?

Comment: @blubberdiblub, so I already organize my data into a specific format and then I use `numpy.save` to save it to the disk.
the `data` from code section 1 would be wrapped in a numpy array  `data = np.array([data])`
and then I will save using numpy way
`np.save('./filepath', data=data)`

I am working with docker linux images. To be honest I am not strongly attached to memmap but I want to have a way to load the data dynamically so I can fit in the physical memory. I need to iterate over all of items I just didn't want to manage that and I was hoping memmap would solve that for me.

Comment: @Kour well, you can do that with the available `memmap()` mechanism if you have all your data in one file. If that works for you, that should not be too hard.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Yea that would be awesome. I tried to do a simple 
`data = np.load('./filepath', mmap_mode = 'r')` and getting
`data_r = data['data']` and iterate over the items by doing `for attr, _ in data_r.items()` but that didn't fit in memory. It is possible that I am missing something or maybe there is another way to deal with this.

Comment: @Kour don't load. Do a `np.memmap()` from the get-go. See the documentation for the `shape=` option.

Comment: @blubberdiblub, I see, this gives me a couple of ideas to try. Thank you I will go and play with it a bit. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: `np.save(..., data=data)` doesn't look right.  `np.savez(..., data=data)` makes more sense, esp. if you use `data['data']` in the load.  But `mmap_mode` doesn't work with `npz` archives.  Use `mmap_mode` when you save a large multidimensional numeric array.  None of this fancy object or nested array stuff.

Comment: Have you tried loading the data into a an SQL database or hdf5? Both are rather good options when it comes to handling data with known types.